# Bundle a typescript project which requires webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I've been working on a project written in Typescript 3.0.1.
WebPack is imported as a dependancy and all works just fine (I use the WebPack NodeJS API).

Finally, I was trying to bundle the whole project (which requires WebPack) with WebPack.

I searched a lot for something similar but I didn't find that someone has done this before.

I get some errors from fsevents and node-pre-gyp which I cannot solve:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js
ERROR in ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/Users/uriahahrak/Desktop/ahrak/witty-cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/Users/uriahahrak/Desktop/ahrak/witty-cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
```

and some warnings from same libraries and from `fsevents.js`.

**I have tried these solutions:**

1. Installing aws-sdk as a dev-dependancy and as a dependancy - that actually removed the errors, but kept the warnings. And the bundle would not work - it throws an error about a `utils.js` file which is not found.
2. Tried to add a noParse property to the WebPack config, and that removed the errors, kept the warnings and again - the bundle would not work because of a `utils.js`.
3. Tried to compile with `tsc`, and then bundle the distributed `js`-file as an entry point. Same errors.

After a lot of searches, the only way it works is with `tsc`, but there are many files generated and I would like to bundle them so it will be used as a standalone `js`-program.

Environment details:

```
node - 8.12.0
npm - 6.4.1
typescript - 3.0.1
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: could you share your webpack configuration? Most of the cases the node_modules folder should be excluded.

Comment: Right you are. solved.